# How to set locale code in CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile method - Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

As there is a parameter LOCALECODE in SetExpressCheckout to display payment page in desired language. Is there any parameter provided for  CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile method to display page in particular language? I have used LOCALECODE as DE to display paypal payment page in german language. Once the user login to paypal, the page again get displayed in english. Is there any way to fix this? I want the whole payment process to be taken in german language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOCALCODE variable allows to set the language on the PayPal checkout page only before they login . But once they login to their PayPal account the language preferences they have set in their PayPal account will be shown . You can set the language for your PayPal account at the below url :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language